# Responsive Navigation with a nested uls

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my website responsive, but I'm having trouble getting my navigation to work correctly. I've tried adjusting the heights, but it's not aligning.

https://jsfiddle.net/ethacker/hcctkjok/2/

I would like the secondary menu (the one that appears when you hover over a parent menu list item) to be the same height as the "parent" menu (the one that says home, pregnancy, all about baby, etc). I use the PHP file extension, but have just pasted the "header" and "header2" code where it would be if it were all in the single file.

```
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <h1><a href="index.php"><img src="mommyinfologo.png"/></h1>
      <ul class="navMenu">
        <a href="index.php">
          <li class="parentMenu">Home
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <a href="mommymadness.php">
                <li>This Mommy's Madness</li>
              </a>
              <a href="about.php">
                <li>About Mommy Info</li>
              </a>
              <a href="contact.php">
                <li>Contact Mommy Info</li>
              </a>
            </ul>

          </li>
        </a>

        <a href="pregnancysplash.php">
          <li class="parentMenu">Pregnancy
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <a href="ttc.php">
                <li>Trying To Conceive</li>
              </a>
              <a href="fetaldev.php">
                <li>Fetal Development</li>
              </a>
              <a href="genderpredictions.php">
                <li>Gender Predictions</li>
              </a>
              <a href="labordelivery.php">
                <li>Labor and Delivery</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="aabsplash.php">
          <li class="parentMenu">All About Baby
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <a href="advice.php">
                <li>Advice</li>
              </a>
              <a href="guidelines.php">
                <li>Guidelines</li>
              </a>
              <a href="milestones.php">
                <li>Milestones</li>
              </a>
              <a href="learndev.php">
                <li>Learning Development</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="healthsplash.php">
          <li class="parentMenu">Health
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <a href="pregnutrition.php">
                <li>Pregnancy Nutrition</li>
              </a>
              <a href="breastfeeding.php">

                <li>Breastfeeding</li>
              </a>
              <a href="formula.php">
                <li>Formula Feeding</li>
              </a>
              <a href="toddlers.php">
                <li>Toddler Nutrition</li>
              </a>
              <a href="preexercise.php">
                <li>Prenatal Exercise</li>
              </a>
              <a href="postexercise.php">
                <li>Postpartum Exercise</li>
              </a>
              <a href="organic.php">
                <li>Organic DIY Health</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="partymommasplash.php">
          <li class="parentMenu">Party Momma
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <a href="pregann.php">
                <li>Pregnancy Announcement</li>
              </a>
              <a href="genderreveal.php">
                <li>Gender Reveal</li>
              </a>
              <a href="babyshower.php">
                <li>Baby Shower</li>
              </a>
              <a href="birthann.php">
                <li>Birth Announcement</li>
              </a>
              <a href="birthdays.php">
                <li>Birthdays</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="stationssplash.php">
          <li class="parentMenu">Stations
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <a href="hospitalbag.php">
                <li>Hospital Bag</li>
              </a>
              <a href="diaperbag.php">
                <li>Diaper Bag</li>
              </a>
              <a href="changingstation.php">
                <li>Changing Station</li>
              </a>
              <a href="babygear.php">
                <li>Baby Gear</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="memorymarkerssplash.php">
          <li class="parentMenu">Memory Markers
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <a href="diymemories.php">
                <li>Do It Yourself</li>
              </a>
              <a href="purchasable.php">
                <li>Buy It</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="reviewsplash.php">
          <li class="parentMenu">Reviews
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <a href="games.php">
                <li>Games</li>
              </a>
              <a href="gear.php">
                <li>Gear</li>
              </a>
              <a href="learning.php">
                <li>Learning</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="mommymadness.php">
          <li class="parentMenu">Blog
          </li>
        </a>

      </ul>
      <?php include_once ("header2.php"); ?>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <!-- Header2.php -->
  <div id="handle">
    <p>☰Menu</p>
    <ul id="navSmall">
      <li class="parentMenuSmall">Home
        <ul class="sub-menu-small">
          <a href="index.php">
            <li>Home</li>
          </a>
          <a href="about.php">
            <li>About</li>
          </a>
          <a href="contact.php">
            <li>Contact</li>
          </a>
          <a href="mommymadness.php">
            <li>Mommy Madness</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parentMenuSmall">Pregnancy
        <ul class="sub-menu-small">
          <a href="pregnancysplash.php">
            <li>Pregnancy</li>
          </a>
          <a href="ttc.php">
            <li>Trying to Conceive</li>
          </a>
          <a href="fetaldev.php">
            <li>Fetal Development</li>
          </a>
          <a href="genderpredictions.php">
            <li>Gender Predictions</li>
          </a>
          <a href="labordelivery.php">
            <li>Labor and Delivery</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parentMenuSmall">All About Baby
        <ul class="sub-menu-small">
          <a href="aabsplash.php">
            <li>All About Baby</li>
          </a>
          <a href="advice.php">
            <li>Advice</li>
          </a>
          <a href="guidelines.php">
            <li>Guidelines</li>
          </a>
          <a href="milestones.php">
            <li>Milestones</li>
          </a>
          <a href="learndev.php">
            <li>Learning Development</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parentMenuSmall">Health
        <ul class="sub-menu-small">
          <a href="healthsplash.php">
            <li>Health and Nutrition</li>
          </a>
          <a href="pregnutrition.php">
            <li>Pregnancy Nutrition</li>
          </a>
          <a href="breastfeeding.php">
            <li>Breastfeeding</li>
          </a>
          <a href="mommymadness.php">
            <li>Formula Feeding</li>
          </a>
          <a href="toddlers.php">
            <li>Toddler Nutrition</li>
          </a>
          <a href="preexercise.php">
            <li>Prenatal Exercise</li>
          </a>
          <a href="postexercise.php">
            <li>Postpartum Exercise</li>
          </a>
          <a href="organic.php">
            <li>Organic DIY Health</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parentMenuSmall">Party Momma
        <ul class="sub-menu-small">
          <a href="partymommasplash.php">
            <li>Party Momma</li>
          </a>
          <a href="pregann.php">
            <li>Pregnancy Announcement</li>
          </a>
          <a href="genderreveal.php">
            <li>Gender Reveal</li>
          </a>
          <a href="babyshower.php">
            <li>Baby Shower</li>
          </a>
          <a href="birthann.php">
            <li>Birth Announcement</li>
          </a>
          <a href="birthdays.php">
            <li>Birthdays</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parentMenuSmall">Stations
        <ul class="sub-menu-small">
          <a href="stationssplash.php">
            <li>Stations</li>
          </a>
          <a href="hospitalbag.php">
            <li>Hospital Bag</li>
          </a>
          <a href="diaperbag.php">
            <li>Diaper Bag</li>
          </a>
          <a href="changingstation.php">
            <li>Changing Station</li>
          </a>
          <a href="babygear.php">
            <li>Baby Gear</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parentMenuSmall">Memory Markers
        <ul class="sub-menu-small">
          <a href="index.php">
            <li>Memory Markers</li>
          </a>
          <a href="diymemories.php">
            <li>Do It Yourself</li>
          </a>
          <a href="purchasable.php">
            <li>Buy It</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parentMenuSmall">Reviews
        <ul class="sub-menu-small">
          <a href="reviewsplash.php">
            <li>Reviews</li>
          </a>
          <a href="games.php">
            <li>Games</li>
          </a>
          <a href="gear.php">
            <li>Gear</li>
          </a>
          <a href="learning.php">
            <li>Learning</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parentMenuSmall">Blog
        <ul class="sub-menu-small">
          <a href="mommymadness.php">
            <li>This Mommy's Madness</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <section class="section" id="home">
    <h2>Welcome to Mommy Info</h2>
    <div>
      Whether you've been there and done that, or you're coming in for your first stop, this is the site for you.
      <p>
        Visit the Pregnancy page to access all kinds of information relating to carrying your little one.
        <br> Visit the All About Baby page to see all sorts of facts about how the baby is growing, advice about raising him or her, and how to encourage healthy development.
        <br> Looking for help deciding how to feed your little one or how to stay fit, visit the Health page!
        <br> Maybe you're looking for ideas to celebrate milestones in your baby's life, check out the Party Momma or Memory Markers tabs!
        <br> Stressed about what to get for your baby? Visit the Stations or Reviews tabs!
        <br> Finally, if you're just wanting to take a gander at the madness that is my life, visit my blog!
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <aside class="section" id="about">
    <h2>You're on the Home Page!</h2>

    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="mmblog.php">The Mommy Behind the Madness</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About Mommy Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Mommy Info</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="hide" id="blogposts">
      <h2>Recent Madness</h2>
      <p>Five Months, and What Have I Done?!</p>
      <p>Four Months, and What Do I Need?</p>
      <p>Three Months, and Help! What's Happening!?</p>
      <p>Two Months</p>
      <p>It's Positive!</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    color:#ADD8E6;
    background-image:url(backgroundarrows.png);
    font-family:"Monotype Corsiva", sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/* Global */
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#737597;
;
}

.section {
    background-color:#fafbff;
    border:thin solid #D3D3D3;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:lightgray 5px 5px 5px;
    color:#696969;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    margin:0 1% 1%;
    padding:5px 8px;
}

.section h2 {
    border-bottom:solid medium #90cdd0;
    color:#90cdd0;
    text-align:center;
}

#about {
    color:dimgrey;
    float:right;
    font-size:medium;
    margin:1% 1% 0;
    text-align:center;
    width:33%;
}

.nav li {
    text-align:left;
    font-size:large;
    padding:1%;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:darkgrey;
}

#home {
    margin:1% 0 1% 1%;
}

#home div {
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:1% 3%;
    text-align:center;
}

#home div p{
    font-family:"Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align:left;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

/* Header */
header {
    background-color:#cff1ff;
    height:60px;
    padding:5px 0;
}

header h1 {
    color:#809dc6;
    display:inline;
    font-family:"Monotype Corsiva", sans-serif;
    font-size:45px;
    height:50px;
    padding:5px 15px;
}

/*Website Navigation */
.navMenu {
    display:inline;
    font-size:20px;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu {
    background-color:#cff1ff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100000;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu:hover{
    background-color:#bfd3ee;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu a{
    color:#737597;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu:hover a:hover{
    color:#87a2be;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu .sub-menu{
    display:none;
    left:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:33px;
    width:180px;
    z-index:10000;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu:hover .sub-menu{
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu:hover .sub-menu li{
    background-color:#bfd3ee;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10000;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu .sub-menu li:hover{
    background-color:#9ac9ed;
}

#handle{
    font-size: 20px;
    display: none;
    color: #87a2be;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

#navSmall {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #cff1ff;
    height: 100%;
}

#handle:hover #navSmall {
    display: inline;
}

.sub-menu-small{
    display: none;
    background-color: #9ac9ed;
    position: relative;
}

.sub-menu-small li {
    border-bottom: solid thin #809dc6;
    padding:1px 3px;
}

#navSmall .parentMenuSmall {
    background-color: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: solid thin #809dc6;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#navSmall .parentMenuSmall:hover .sub-menu-small {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
#construct {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    border-radius: 20%;
}


/* Media Queries */
/*tablet*/
/*remove floats */
@media(max-width: 768px) {
    body{
        width: 100%;
    }
    header {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 120px;
    }

    .section{
        width: 95%;
    }

    #about{
        display: none;
    }

    #handle{
        display: block;
    }

    .navMenu {
        display: none;
    }

}

/* Tables on Diaper Bag*/
table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

table th {
    font-size: 28px;
}

table td {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#main {
    color: #66CDAA;
}

#quick {
    color: #809dc6;
}

#car {
    color: #95b6c0;
}

#item, .item {
    color: #9c9c9c;
}

.mainBag {
    background-color: rgba(102, 205, 170, 0.1);
}
.toiletries {
    background-color: rgba(128, 157, 198, 0.1);
}

.firstAid {
    background-color: rgba(149, 182, 192, 0.1);
}
table td {
    border: solid thin gray;
    border-top:none;
    border-right: none;
}

.right {
    background-color: palegreen;
}

.wrong {
    background-color: #ffc5b7;
}

.girl {
    background-color: lightpink;
}

.boy {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.section p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
}

.items {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
    color: #95b6c0;
}

.itemDesc{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #6b6b6b;
}
```

Comment: Why did you make the HTML so complicated for something so simple?

Comment: What do you mean?